# New route or another way to call a function from controller with ajax? Laravel 5.2 , Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, session

Is it possible to call a function in the controller without using a route or should I make a new route with two parameters as below that redirects to the specific page after the session has been added?

`route::get('addsesion/{session-name}/{session slug};`

If it's possible with ajax, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Basically what I would like to do is call the function `addSession($session_name, $slug)` from a controller with ajax on link `<a href/>` click , where it stores my specific session name and current page's slug.

It should call this `addSession` function on a click, store session data and then redirect to a different url. e.g. `/seeparts`, where it displays all saved session data.

Do I have to make a new `route route::get('addsesion/{param1 - session-name}/{param2 - session slug}', currentController@addSession );` and then use that route as an ajax url? Or is there any other way how to use the controller's function?

**My current Controller:**

```
public function showAll() {
  $parts = \DB::table() - > all();
  $data = [
    'parts' => $parts,
  ];
  return view('partlist', $data);
}

public function showCpu($slug) {
  // Specification query
  $specs = \DB::table() - > select($select_columns) - > where('slug', $slug) - > first();
  $data = [
    'specs' => $specs,
    'slug' => $slug
  ];
  return view('part', $data);
}

//Add session - call this function
public function addSession($session_name, $slug) {\
  Session::put($session_name, $slug);
}
}
```

**part.blade.php:**

```
<html>
@include('head.blade.php')
</body>
     //on .add-to-partlist click adds session name that is specified in html and the current slug of the page
    <a class="add-to-partlist" href="/seeparts" >Add to partlist</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think returning a json from the method and (ofc you need a route ) using ajax would be a better solution (simpler) and in success of the ajax call you can redirect to the other page, in case of error dont redirect and display an error, this is what i'll do if i were u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use `Service Injection` binding controller function in your view.
Maybe you can reference it, https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#service-injection.

For example:

```
<html>
@include('head.blade.php')
@inject('currentController', 'App\Http\Controllers\currentController')
</body>
     //on .add-to-partlist click adds session name that is specified in html and the current slug of the page
    <a class="add-to-partlist" href="/seeparts" onClick="{{ $currentController->addSession($session_name, $slug) }}">HERE</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also i would like to thank people who edited my question to be more understandable.